# get page source after filling the value in text box

Tags: php, pdf

i develop a webpage in that i have a registration form that allow users to enter their personal information . After filling the form , user can click the button , i need to create a PDF as same as in the Registration form [including colour , picture,Entered value etc..] Please help me to solve this issue . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [html2ps / html2pdf](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

We had a lot of difficulty getting html2ps to do what we wanted.